# How to set a "require" to return a table/module from Lua C API?

Tags: c, lua

I want to add a `require`able module solely from the C API.

```
--lua.lua
local c_module = require("c_module")
c_module.doWork()
```

What API functions do I have to use to make this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When loading a shared library with `require`, Lua looks for a a function named `luaopen_<name>` where `<name>` is the module name with the dots replaced with underscores (so `require "foo.bar"` will look for `luaopen_foo_bar`, but hyphens get special treatment; see the Lua manual).

This function should be a regular `lua_CFunction`; that is, it takes a `lua_State*` as an argument and returns an `int`. `require` calls this function with the package name as an argument, and the value you return from the function is what `require` stores and returns.

Here's an example for a module named `foo`:

```
static int bar(lua_State* L) {
    // ...
}

int luaopen_foo(lua_State* L) {
    lua_newtable(L); // Create package table

    // Push and assign each function
    lua_pushcfunction(L, &bar);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "bar");

    // ...

    // Return package table
    return 1;
}
```

(This is for Lua 5.1, though the equivalent code for 5.2 should be very similar, if not the same. Also be sure that the `luaopen_` function is exported from the shared library.)

The full behavior of the C loader can be found here: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loaders

Comment: If there should be no separate library called `foo.so/.dll`, the function luaopen_foo has to be registered as cclosure as `package.preload.foo`. This is simply done: `lua_getglobal(l, "package");
 lua_pushstring(l, "preload");
 lua_gettable(l, -2);
 lua_pushcclosure(l, luaopen_test, 0);
 lua_setfield(l, -2, "test");
 lua_settop(l, 0);`. This way it can be defined directly in the main program.

Comment: @Appleshell: Or, if you don't mind also executing your `luaopen_test()`, you can use Lua 5.2's `luaL_requiref()`, which stores the module in `packae.loaded[modname]`.